# Can you teleport or Dimension Door out of your clothes?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, teleportation

I've got a warlock with Flee The Scene, a *dimension door* spell-like ability. He's been attacked by monstrous spiders and has 1 STR left, meaning his 15lbs of armour alone is more than a heavy load.

He's not grappled, and he's not unable to move as he would be at 0 STR. Can he use Flee The Scene to jump out of his clothes and sprint naked for freedom?

Comment: To clarify, is the warlock wearing actual armor that takes [time to get into and out of](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/armor.html#table-donning-armor) or just clothes? Because if wearing only clothes, keep in mind that a character's "first outfit is free and does not count against the amount of weight a
character can carry" (*PH* 131).

Comment: Yeah: is the title poetic/amusing and not literal, and the actual situation involves proper armour (a suit of Leather, judging by the weight)?

Answer (score 23):

**Yes**, you can.

The exact wording of [Dimension Door](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/dimensionDoor.htm) is

> You **can** bring along objects as long as their weight doesn’t exceed your maximum load.

So it is you to decide, whether you bring your armour with you or not.

I would say that you can even choose what to bring with you and what to leave behind. But if your new maximum load is lower than the total weight of your possessions then you are not allowed to bring everything.

Both [Teleport](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/teleport.htm) and [Teleport, Greater](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/teleportGreater.htm) work the same way.

> You **can** bring along objects as long as their weight doesn’t exceed your maximum load.

Comment: It's not quite that you aren't _allowed_ to bring everything, but that you really _shouldn't_.

Comment: @Javelin if the weight of the armor exceeds the character's carrying capacity,  then you really aren't allowed to bring it.

Comment: Now I'm going to do this all the time just for kicks.

Comment: Oh, wow. This finally answers a question I've been wondering about for years but never got around to asking: Whether you can leave the rope behind if you teleport while tied up.

Answer (score 10):

#### Yes, you can.

> ... You can bring along objects as long as their weight doesn’t exceed your maximum load...

Note, the spell says "can", not "must". More of it, you just can't take your armor with you, as it's weight exceeds your new maximum load.

Answer (score 7):

## Yes

The *Dragon* #347 Sage Advice column "Official Answers to Your Questions" includes this exchange:

> **Can you choose not to bring along an item you carry when you cast *teleport*? If you're manacled, can you *teleport* out of the manacles?**
>
> The *teleport* spell states that you "can" bring along objects, which indicates that it isn't mandatory. Thus a manacled wizard could cast *teleport* to free herself from captivity. (81)

…Or, presumably, a warlock could use an effect like the lesser invocation *flee the scene* (*Complete Arcane* 134)—the effect of which is based on the spell [*dimension door*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsDtoE.html#dimension-door) which has language identical to the spell [*teleport*](http://www.systemreferencedocuments.org/resources/systems/pennpaper/dnd35/soveliorsage/spellsTtoZ.html#teleport)—to remove armor or weighty garments (which I assume is usually an *easier* task than removing manacles).

***Note:** The Sage at the time was [Andy Collins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andy_Collins_(game_designer)), primary architect of the* Dungeons and Dragons 3.5 *revision. While* Dragon *magazine was not published by Wizards of the Coast when this column was released, the* 100% Official Content *seal on the cover of remains.*

Answer (score -1):

GM call. As a GM I've allowed it in the past; but only if everything gets left behind. Spellcasting is a hurried affair in combat and the grappled person doesn't have time to take a mental inventory to cherry pick what he brings with and what gets left behind. Others might rule this exploit or outside the intent of the spell (I don't know why, but...) YMMV.

Clarification: the character I made the ruling on had gotten webbed and was caught by several articles of clothing. Not a direct parallel, but there are similarities.

Comment: There are two problems I see with this answer. First of all, this is a rules question—a good answer should reference the rules in some fashion, even if it is to assert that no rules touch on this (though I’m not sure that’s true in this case). Second, while it’s nice to know what you have done in your games, your experience is much more valuable as an answer if you can go into more details on how your ruling worked.