# How much control do you have over what's moved with teleportation magic?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, teleportation

My question concerns teleportation effects like the [teleport](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/teleport) spell or [warp sphere](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/variant-magic-rules/spheres-of-power/using-the-spheres/#Warp) from SoP over [dimensional door](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/d/dimension-door/).

When the spell is cast, would you be able to leave behind something you are touching, such as [manacles](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment/goods-and-services/tools-kits/#TOC-Manacles) or even worn clothing (no, I do not plan on stripping people, just if a disguise is ruined you can abandon it for the one you are wearing underneath).

Comment: [Related for *3.5e.*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/90467/8610)

Comment: Same wording on the Pathfinder spell as on the 3.5 spell, I'd call that a dup target.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie I did not know that about the magic and spells tags. Thank you for mentioning it and making the correction.